# boost::locale::conv utf8 to cp437

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, localization

For last two days I've been trying to convert `utf-8` string to `cp437` string and I've already tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8442082/1149736).

Example situation would be converting [`char *utf8="\xC2\xBB"`](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) to [`char *cp437="\xAF"`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cp437#Standard_code_page) (or 175  decimal if you will).

I came up with many variations of this:

```
struct ConsoleOutputWrapper {
    boost::locale::generator generator;

    std::string c_output; // Charset name
    std::locale l_output; // Locale

    ConsoleOutputWrapper() :
        generator(),
        c_output("CP437")
    {
        generator.locale_cache_enabled(true);
        l_output = generator(c_output);
    }

    void operator<<(const char* str)
    {
        std::cout << boost::locale::conv::from_utf<char>(str, l_output);
    }
};

// Test
ConsoleOutputWrapper k;
k << "\xc2\xbb";
```

But the best conversion I've got to was `>` instead of `»`.

Any ideas how to convert special characters like these using boost?

Comment: You would have to check the documentation but boost may not have a good mapping for that. You might want to try the [ICU library](http://site.icu-project.org/) instead

Comment: @Mgetz I'd consider that to be a perfectly valid answer :) although I prefer some references for things like this. Anyway as far as I can tell, [boost can be told to be compiled with ICU](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/locale/doc/html/building_boost_locale.html).

Comment: If I had them I would have posted as an answer, generally though people seem to be recommending ICU for handling character set handling in C++ so I thought I would mention it so you could make up your own mind.