# Need working sample code of _wcstombs_l

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

How do I use _wcstombs_l function to convert a UNICODE string to UTF-8? I guess I need to pass in a UTF-8 _locale_t, but I don't know how to create a variable of this type.

Comment: first result on google working example -[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d7tc9zw.aspx]

Comment: Please read my question - I want to convert to UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't - UTF-8 is not really an ANSI code page, there's no locale that uses it. Use `WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, ...)` instead.

You are supposed to create a `_locale_t` argument for `_wcstombs_l` with `_create_locale` function. [Its documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zx9aht2.aspx) states, and I quote:

> The *locale* argument can take a locale name, a language string, a language string and country/region code, a code page, or a language string, country/region code, and code page. The set of available locale names, languages, country/region codes, and code pages includes all that are supported by the Windows NLS API except the code pages that require more than two bytes per character - for example, UTF-7 and **UTF-8**. If you provide a code page like UTF-7 or **UTF-8**, `_create_locale` will **fail** and return `NULL`.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Okay... This means I had a misunderstanding of this convenient function. :-(

Comment: I came across this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859638/stumped-with-unicode-boost-c-codecvts. I think it's quite possible to convert from/to UTF-8 using the _locale_t parameter, but don't know how to create the locale without using boost.

Comment: `std::locale` and `_locale_t` are two different beasts. The latter is a Microsoft-specific invention for use with Microsoft-specific C-style library calls like `_wcstombs_l`. You create one with a (needless to say) Microsoft-specific function `_create_locale`.

Comment: Thanks! I had another misunderstanding!